# How to selecting data where the date is with the next month or later

Tags: mysql, date-format

I want to display all data where the the expiry date is within next month or later, here is my code:

```
<cfquery name="ExpiryDate"> 
        SELECT * 
        FROM Date
        WHERE Expiry >= 

</cfquery>
```

Comment: "Within next month" do you mean in the future?

Comment: yes in the future

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Date
    WHERE Expiry >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

MySQL date and time functions are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).